# how to handle duplicated v-slot names in vee-validate

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

Let's say that I have a code like:

```html
<Form
  v-slot="{ errors }"
  as="v-form"
>
  <v-card-text>
    <Field
      name="username"
      v-slot="{ field, errors }"
      rules="required"
    >
      <v-text-field
        v-bind="field"
        v-model="username"
        label="user"
        :error-messages="errors"
      ></v-text-field>
    </Field>
    <Field
      name="password"
      v-slot="{ field, errors }"
      rules="required"
    >
      <!-- keyup.enter should print errors of Form's v-slot -->
      <v-text-field
        v-bind="field"
        v-model="password"
        label="password"
        :error-messages="errors"
        v-on:keyup.enter="() => {console.log(errors)}"
      ></v-text-field>
    </Field>
  </v-card-text>
</Form>
```

[Field](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field/) and [Form](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/form/) are `vee-validate` components.

In this code I want to `console.log` `errors` of `Form`'s `v-slot`. But password `Field`'s `errors` is printed out. How to separate `errors` of `Form` and `errors` of `Field` slots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

destructed slot properties [may be renamed](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/discussions/3814) (`errors` → `formErrors`):

```html
<Form
  v-slot="{ errors: formErrors }"
  as="v-form"
>
  <v-card-text>
    ...
    <Field
      v-slot="{ field, errors }"
      ...
    >
      <v-text-field
        ...
        :error-messages="errors"
        v-on:keyup.enter="() => {console.log(formErrors)}"
      ></v-text-field>
    </Field>
  </v-card-text>
</Form>
```